# which function to use for jquery while scrolling sidebars

Tags: jquery

I have one image. i want that when someone scrolls the browser window then by jquery i should also change the image position from top as well

I want to use jquery only . Is there function like that.

I don't want to use `position:fixed` or something like that. I want something like

```
onScroll(){
var x = getScrollDIstance();
moveImageDown(x);

}
```

Comment: Why not use the `position:fixed` option? It does what you need, and likely will work faster.

Comment: Because that will make the image fixed at particular position , but i want that at near bottom , the image should not scroll. so that's why i wanted to use jquery so that if image reaches certain height , it should stop scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping with your requirement of not using `position:fixed`, you can do the following with jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{
  $('#your-image').animate({top:$(window).scrollTop()+"px" },{queue: false, duration: 350});
});
```